# CKEDITOR jQuery Validation in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, ckeditor

I have 2 CKEditor fields that are being validated for input by jquery. Everything works perfect except in Firefox. For some reason, it doesn't check for those fields unless the CKEDITOR fields received input first. So, basically, if you enter the page and click on submit form button, it won't check for those fields, but if you put cursor inside the fields and try to validate then, it works. again, that only happens in Firefox.

The validation code is very simple:

```
var edt1 = CKEDITOR.instances['div1'].getData();

if (!edt1) {
    AppendErrorMessage("message.");
    ShowValidationIcon($('#icon'));
}
return true;
```

Any workaround to this problem?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem myself.

It was due to the fact that Firefox was automatically placing a bit of HTML, so the field wasn't actually empty.

here's the code that solved the problem for all browsers.

    if (edt1 == "" || edt1 === "<br />\n") {
        do stuff
    }

Comment: You should answer your own question, so this doesn't come up in the 'unanswered' questions search.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem myself.

It was due to the fact that Firefox was automatically placing a bit of HTML, so the field wasn't actually empty. Here's the code that solved the problem for all browsers.

```
if (edt1 == "" || edt1 === "<br />\n") { do stuff }
```